# Set child to programmatically-created object in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

As said in the title, Ive created a scrollviewer to see all files in x folder.

```
string filesLocation = folderLocation + "\\Files";
            string[] allFilesArray = Directory.GetFiles(@filesLocation);

            //int fileNumber = 0;
            int MarginTop = 0;
            foreach (var file in allFilesArray)
            {
                Border fileBorder = new Border
                {
                    Margin = new Thickness(0, MarginTop, 0, 0),
                    Height = 20,
                    Background = Brushes.Transparent,
                    BorderBrush = (SolidColorBrush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFromString("#f333"),
                    BorderThickness = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 1),
                    HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left,
                    VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top,
                    Name = file
                };

                System.Windows.Controls.Label fileName = new System.Windows.Controls.Label
                {
                    Foreground = (SolidColorBrush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFromString("#f333"),
                    Padding = new Thickness(3),
                    Content = file,
                    Name = file + ":FILE_LABEL"
                };

                filesGrid.Children.Add(fileBorder);

                MarginTop += 20;
            }

            filesCant.Content = "Files: " + allFilesArray.Length;
```

This is my WPF Xaml code where I want to insert my border:

```
<Border BorderBrush="#f555" BorderThickness="1" Margin="5,5,5,5" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="1">
                            <Grid>
                                <Border BorderBrush="#f555" Height="30" Margin="-1, 0, -1, -1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" BorderThickness="1">
                                    <Label Content="FIles: " Foreground="#f555" x:Name="filesCant"/>
                                </Border>
                                <Border BorderBrush="#f555" Height="20" Margin="-1, 0, -1, -1" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderThickness="1">
                                    <Label Content="Files" Padding="0" Foreground="#f555" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                                </Border>
                                <ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="0,20,0,30">
                                    <Grid x:Name="filesGrid">
                                        
                                    </Grid>
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
```

But here is the problem. I want the fileName Label to be a child of fileBorder, but I cant because when I add

```
fileBorder.Children.Add(fileLabel);
```

I get

> 'Border' has no definition for 'Children' and no accessible method called 'Children' accepting a first argument of type 'border' found. (Are yo missing an assembly reference?)

My code is using System.Windows.Controls and System.Windows.Forms. Is there any way to add the label as children to the border?

Comment: `Border` does not allow multiple children. It is `Child`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A border control only has a single [Child](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.decorator.child?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Controls_Decorator_Child) rather than multiple children.

You could create the desired effect by setting the border's child as a StackPanel and adding your labels to that.

However, you're missing out on one of the key powers of WPF - templating. Set your allFilesArray as the items source for an ItemsControl (e.g. ListBox or ListView) with an appropriate ItemTemplate. You can then create your UI by placing this control within the border.